# Text and Image Rotation at Same Time

Tags: javascript, css, coldfusion-9

I've used this code below for a simple and easy image rotation with link.

Trying to find an easy way to add an additional description or textlink also with the rotation at the same time...  Been snooping around and can't find easy solution.

So looking for a description that can be displayed beside the image as well at same time.

```
<a id="imageurl"><img id="Rotating1" border="0" height=250 width=375></a>

<script language="JavaScript">

function RotateImages(Start)
{
    var a = new Array("images/signs.png","images/sister.png");
    var c = new Array("index.cfm", "index.cfm");
    var b = document.getElementById('Rotating1');
    var d = document.getElementById('imageurl');
    if(Start>=a.length)
        Start=0;
    b.src = a[Start];
    d.href = c[Start];
    window.setTimeout("RotateImages(" + (Start+1) + ")",5700);
}

RotateImages(0);
</script>
```

I have found one using google ajax... Works ok...
Now to get the CSS all sorted out to get it displaying right...
Any suggestions?  I'm just trying to use link and text on left side and image on right side...
Display and rotates fine - just off a bit... I'm not best with all the position: relative etc css stuff...

```
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script>
    $(function() {

        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  2000);

    });
</script>




      <cfset slw = #set.mw# - 100>

      <cfoutput>

      <STYLE type="text/css">

    ##slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: #slw#px; 
    height: 200px; 
    padding: 10px;
background-color: #set.botcol#;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 

      }


      ##slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 

      } 

      </style>

      </cfoutput>


      <div id="slideshow">

   <cfoutput query=slide>
   <div>
   <table border=1 width=#slw# cellspacing=5 cellpadding=5>
   <tr>
   <td width=50% align=right valign=top>
   <br><a href="#slideurl#">#slidetext#</a></td>
   <td width=50%><img src="images/#slideimg#" height=200></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   </cfoutput>

     </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` with strings, it's like evil `eval`! Use functions instead: `setTimeout(function(){ RotateImages(Start+1); }, 5700)`

Comment: Do you want the description to be HTML, or is raw text fine?

Comment: HTML Preferred as I could play with it a bit more...

Comment: it would help if both setTimeout/setInterval use the same timeout or interval (5700 or 2000) and start in the same time. adding RotateImages(0); inside the $(function() { ... })

Comment: kitty! http://jsfiddle.net/mKTSX/